# Page table calculations

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, page-tables

Physical memory is 2^20 bytes
Logical address space is 2048 pages
Page size is 4KB

1. How long is the page table?
2. Each page table entry contains valid/invalid bit in addition to the page frame number,how wide is the page table?
3. Consider a process which is allowed to use only addresses 0 to 30000 of logical address space. How many entries in the page table should be set as valid?
4. Is there any internal or external fragmentation? Explain.
5. If a system use inverted page table how many entries are in the page table?

Please HELP! My exam is tomorrow

Comment: I want you to do my exam prep for me.  Explain.

Comment: What's prep? If you can't help then mind your own business.

Comment: You posted on here.  If I wanted it to be my business, I would invoice you up front.

Comment: You're suppose to help and guide people here, not to show off how rude you are.

Comment: I asked this particular question cause I couldn't figure out the answer. So if you don't know the answer the least you could do is not to put insulting comments. Anyone can insult but not everyone can answer a question right.

Answer (score -1):

Well I think I found the answer not 100% sure.

1. 2048 pages
2. 23+1= 24 bits
3. 30000/4*1024=  approximately 7 pages
4. Yes (not sure how??)

5.2^20 / 4*1024 =256 pages

Comment: There is no answer to the problem as posed. What textbook is this nonsense coming from?